# JS SDK - Posting to a page wall

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

I am using the JavaScript SDK. I have an application that has publishing permissions and after certain actions are taken a post will be made to the logged in users wall like so:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    //we are authorized
    if (response.status == "connected") {
        var name = "Post name";
        var body = "Post body";
        var caption = "The caption";
        var description = "The description";
        var link = "http://www.facebook.com/mypage";
        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message:body,caption:caption,link:link,name:name,description:description}, function (response) {
       console.log(response);
        });
    }
});
```

What I would like to able to do is post to a specific Facebook Page after a post is successfully made to the users page. Is there a way to securely pre-authorize an application to do that? Is this possible with the JavaScript SDK, or at all? I did some looking around and havn't found a definite answer. I'm looking at the FB documentation but find it to be a bit spotty in places. Could anyone tell me if this is possible? Any help or advice would be very much appreciated, thanks much!

**Edit:** my mistake, I should have supplied more info. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
var body = "The body";
var caption = "The caption";
FB.api("mypageid/feed", "post", { message: body, caption: caption }, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

I am getting the error `"this api call requires a valid app_id"` however my page id is valid. When I call `FB.init()` I am passing my app id and it works for the first post to the logged in users feed.

**Edit:**

I have made the change the Igy suggested. Now I am getting the error:""(#200) The user has not granted the application the permission to automatically publish feed stories""

Now, as I said I am trying to post to a Facebook page. I have logged into the account that owns the page and I have gone to the app and clicked allow for the following permissions:

```
email,user_photos,publish_stream
```

When I am logged in with the account that owns the page and check my status:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

I get "connected". Am I doing this incorrectly? Do I have to do more than just authorize with the account that owns the page? Is there a way to set allow permissions for a page? I did a little digging but couldn't find an answer.

**Edit** :
Ok, now what is happening is IF I am logged into the account that owns the page the post will be made to the page. If I am logged in with another account I get an id back as a response to the API call but it doesn't seem to be a valid object id. For instance I just got this back:

```
id: 499973616681852_507724422573438
```

if I go to `http://graph.facebook.com/499973616681852_507724422573438`

I get an "`unsupported get request"` graph api exception, which suggest that id returned is not valid. I feel like I am close here but I am missing something. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks again to all who responded.

edit: removed the link to the page,that was left in unintentionally.

Comment: What is it you're having trouble with, posting to another page?

Comment: You should be able to just make another API call to `/PAGE_ID/feed` - is this nor working for you? if not, what error are you getting?

Comment: Thank you both for responses. @Igy my post has been edited.

Comment: Are you missing the '/' in the call to post to the page's feed? are you definitely doing this on the same page and aren't losing the FB object you used to make the 'user post' API call?

Comment: @Igy thanks for the response, you were right about the forward slash. However now I am getting a permissions error. I updated the above.

Comment: Does the Facebook page _allow_ posts to it’s wall by users in its settings?

Comment: There are a couple of things that still aren't clear:  1) Do you want the post to the page appear as if the user posted it, or as if the page itself made the post? 2) Who 'owns' the page?  Is it a specific page you own or does the end user own the page?

Comment: @ToddChaffee thanks for the reply. I want it to appear as if the page itself made the post. I have access to the account that owns the page. I've logged into that account, navigated to a page that has the app on it(this is the only way I could figure out how to do it) and granted the 'manage pages' permission.

Comment: I added some more instructions to my answer about how to authenticate as a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good practice to try getting it to work in the [graph explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) first.  Note that on the top right you can select which application to run under.  I just made a post to your page using /PAGE_ID/feed and it worked fine.  You'll need the publish_stream permission.  If you can get it to work in the graph explorer you'll know it's possible to get it to work in the JS SDK and you've just made some sort of syntax error.

Also note there is an [open high priority bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/160155304123891?browse=search_5068c0031d0087976417345) on some calls to the graph returning "unsupported get request".  So even though the id you are getting back is invalid, check the page itself to see if the posts are appearing.

I also noticed that the user itself is getting the same error.  Try https://graph.facebook.com/507724422573438.  Is this a test user for your app?  Might be worth trying this as a real user if so.

Since you want to post to the page as the page itself, you'll need to [authenticate as a page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) and then use that access token when making graph api calls.  I am not sure if you'll be able to then use this access token for *any* user, or only users that are allowed to manage the page.  It would be best for you to use the graph explorer to do some experiments to find out.

Comment: Hi,thank you very much for the response. Forgive the lateness of my reply I was tied up all day yesterday. When you say that you posted to the page using pageid/feed did you pass in values using the query string? Something like (in the graph api explorer) pageid/feed?message=themessage ? I'm looking through the documentation but am having a difficult time finding concrete examples or descriptions of how things work. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: I passed the message as POST value.  The graph explorer lets you build it up just by clicking.